# Error al guardar un archivo PDF generado con fpdf en WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, fpdf, html2canvas

Hola estoy haciendo un sencillo plugin para *WordPress* que al dar click en un botón de una página creo una captura de pantalla con la librería *html2canvas*, esta captura es enviada a un archivo PHP que con la librería *FPDF* creo un documento con esa imagen y lo intento enviar por correo.

El problema es que el siguiente código me funciona bien en el proyecto local que tengo con XAMPP, (es decir me crea la imagen temp y el archivo PDF) pero cuando ese mismo lo pongo online para probar enviar ese pdf por correo, no me guarda los archivos, he leído un poco y creo que el problema es al usar **DIR** , también intente con `esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . 'wp-content/plugins/miplugin/pdf/archivo.pdf'`.

¿Qué me recomiendan'. Saludos y gracias de antemano.

```
//Conectar Mailer
    require __DIR__ . "/PHPMailer.php";
    require __DIR__ . "/SMTP.php";
    require __DIR__ . "/Exception.php";
    require __DIR__ . "/PHPMailerAutoload.php";


    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP; 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload;


    require __DIR__ . "/fpdf/fpdf.php";

    $dato = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


    $captura = $dato->captura;
    $emailPDF = $dato->emailPDF;
    // Aquí obtener más datos si existen...

    $TEMP = __DIR__ . 'temp.png';

    // Quitar "data:image..." de la cadena
    $capturaLimpia = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", urldecode($captura));
    //Venía codificada pero sólo la codificamos así para que viajara por la red,
    //ahora la decodificamos y
    //guardamos el contenido dentro de un archivo
    $imagenDecodificada = base64_decode($capturaLimpia);

    if ( file_put_contents($TEMP, $imagenDecodificada) != false ) {

        // create new PDF document
        $pdf = new FPDF('p', 'mm', array(120, 400));
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->Image($TEMP, -10, 5, 130, 400, '', '');
        $data = $pdf->Output('a.pdf', 'S');

        unlink($TEMP);
    
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
        try {
            $mail->isSMTP(); 
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
            $mail->Username = '';
            $mail->Password = '';  
            $mail->Port = 587; 

            //Recipients 
            $mail->setFrom('@gmail.com', 'Mailer'); 
            $mail->addAddress($emailPDF, 'Joe User'); 
            $mail->isHTML(true); 

            // Set email format to HTML 
            $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject'; 

            $mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>'; 

            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients'; 

            //Attachments
            $mail->addStringAttachment($data, 'fichero.pdf');
            $mail->AddStringAttachment($data, 'reserva-greg.pdf', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');

            $mail->send(); 

            //echo 'Message has been sent'; 
            $r = "Succes sending email";
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}"; 
            $r = "Failed sending email";
        }   

        $hoy = date("Y-m-d--U");

        $urlPDF = __DIR__ . "MiPDF-" . $hoy . $r . ".pdf";

        file_put_contents( $urlPDF, $data );

    }
```

Comment: Dinos dónde te interesa guardar el archivo ¿? Si usas WP, puedes usar sus funciones propias para referirte a las rutas. Si algo no funciona, depura el código, por ejemplo, imprimiendo el valor que produciría la ruta y verificando que es correcto (que la ruta/archivo existen en ese lugar). Lo que te ocurre es que no estás depurando tu códig, conviene que aprendas a hacerlo.

Comment: Hola, intento guardar el archivo en la misma carpeta del plugin que hice, si comprobé que la ruta está bien, y en mi proyecto en localhost con Xampp si me crea y guarda bien el archivo, es cuando pongo el proyecto en un sitio online q no me lo hace. Soy un poco nueva en esto pudieras indicarme con q funciones pudiera probar las rutas además de las 2 que ya utilicé

Comment: Para hacer referencia al directorio de plugins de WP, puedes usar [`plugins_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/). En el apartado [*User Contributed Notes*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/#user-contributed-notes) tienes ejemplos de casos concretos.

Comment: Gracias voy a estudiarmelo